# How to choose the right size bike?

Tags: frames, bike-fit, fixed-gear

This question is one that I'm sure has been beat to death, but I am new to bike riding. Ideally I would have bought the bike at a local bike shop and been fit for the perfect bike. However, the prices at the local shops where I live are pretty steep. So this is my predicament.

I am approx. 5'6" to 5'7" (Please resist the urge. I know I'm a manlet.)

My inseam is roughly 29.5".

The frame size of the bike I ordered is 50cm and the sizing chart is below.

[image]

Did I get the right size?

Comment: I realize that the image is a sizing chart but my problem is that I seem to be pretty much between sizes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as the asker says, it already has multiple answers here. Maybe this search would work: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=bike+size

Comment: ...and this is the problem with buying online.    Sight-unseen is just too risky, not everyone is built like average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will never really know until you get a fitting and ride it for some time, then you can really say, "Oh I wish I had gotten a bike with less reach", or "Man, I wish I had gotten a frame more less trail or a shorter wheelbase.

50cm actually seems a bit small for someone 5'7" (I would think 52-54).  But, there are numerous adjustments you one can make once one has ridden the bike and knows the pain points.  Also, recommendations for sizing vary depending on the manufacturer and what type of bike it is.

Other than fitting charts which you have obviously found and used, you need to be on the bike to know if it fits *you*, not just a generic person who is 5'7".

Comment: That's what I was afraid. I suppose I just needed to hear someone else say it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to cycling... I would say you made about as good of choice as you could have given the information.  I know two people 5'7" and one likes 52cm frames and the other 48-50CM frames.  The point is, the difference is subject to preference based on body type (e.g. short legs-long torso vs long legs-short torso).

Once you get the bike there will be a number of adjustments (seat height, seat position, handlebar height) etc that can be made to dial things in just right.

Finally, really try to understand the frame geometry of this bike so if and when you get your next bike you are vary familiar with the specs what you like what you wished was different etc... so you make the best possible choice in the future.

Comment: My biggest concern was that I have ridden bikes that were too big and it isn't fun and can be dangerous. The same I guess goes for bikes that are too small. It's interesting to hear that preference has a lot to do with it. I will keep all of that in mind if and when I get a different one. Thanks.

Comment: The comment I give people... figure out what size you think you need then subtract a centimeter.  I find it is better to have "room to adjust in the cockpit" than be layed out unable to bend the elbows, arch the back, push back on the saddle, etc..

Comment: that is a good idea.